# Dropping an existing constraint in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have tried to drop an existing constraint. Here's what I have:

The name of the constraint is: `Data.Leraar.IsGeheim.DefaultValue`
and the name of the table is: `Data.Leraa`.

This is the command I'm currently using:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Leraar'))
 BEGIN 
ALTER TABLE Data.Leraar DROP CONSTRAINT [Data.Leraar.IsGeheim.DefaultValue]
END
```

If I execute this command, it says `Command(s) completed successfully.`
But the constraint still exists.

How should I change this command?

So you mean like this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Leraar'))
 BEGIN 

ALTER TABLE DataData.Leraar DROP FOREIGN KEY IsGeheim.DefaultValue;
END
```

But then I will get an error

Sorry, but I am using microsoft SQL

if I just do an simple:

```
    ALTER TABLE [Data].[Leraar] DROP CONSTRAINT [Data.Leraar.IsGeheim.DefaultValue]
    GO

it works. But I first want to check if it exists

If I do it like this:

IF exists (
    SELECT * 
    FROM sys.default_constraints 
    WHERE 
        parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'Data.Leraar') and
        name  = 'Data.Leraar.IsGeheim.DefaultValue'
)
    ALTER TABLE Data.Leraar Drop Constraint Data.Leraar.IsGeheim.DefaultValue
GO
```

I get error on this line

```
 ALTER TABLE Data.Leraar Drop Constraint Data.Leraar.IsGeheim.DefaultValue
```

after Data. I get error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15 Incorrect syntax near '.'.

This works:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Leraar'))
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [Data].[Leraar] ADD  CONSTRAINT [Data.Leraar.IsGeheim.DefaultValue]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [IsGeheim]
END
```

But to drop if it exists doens work

I have it now like this:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM sys.default_constraints 
    WHERE 
        parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'Data.Leraar') and
        name  = 'Data.Leraar.IsGeheim.DefaultValue'
)
    ALTER TABLE Data.Leraar Drop Constraint [Data.Leraar.IsGeheim.DefaultValue]
    PRINT 'constraint [Data.Leraar.IsGeheim.DefaultValue] has been dropped'
GO

IF NOT EXISTS((SELECT 1 FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Leraar') AND name ='Data.Leraar.IsGeheim.DefaultValue'))
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [Data].[Leraar] ADD  CONSTRAINT [Data.Leraar.IsGeheim.DefaultValue]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [IsGeheim]
PRINT 'Constraint has been created [Data.Leraar.IsGeheim.DefaultValue]'
END
```

But is this correct?

Comment: If you know the `name` of the constraint, why don't you actually use that? It's right there in `sys.foreign_keys`. Your current logic assumes there's no more than one foreign key, which seems wrong even if it actually worked. To correctly select a foreign key based on source and destination tables and columns when you don't know the name, you'd also need to pull in `sys.foreign_key_columns`.

Comment: Add DDL for your tables, including the constraints. You are checking for a foreign key constraint on `dbo.Leraar` but specifying `Data.Leraar` on the `ALTER TABLE` statement. It's unclear if `Data` is the schema name or part of the table name.

Comment: Please post the results of this query: `SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'Data.Leraar')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also query sys.default_constraints system view as follows including the DROP Constraint clause of ALTER TABLE command

Please replace the table name and constraint name according to your case

```
IF exists (
    SELECT * 
    FROM sys.default_constraints 
    WHERE 
        parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'Table_1') and
        name  = 'DF_Table_1_col1'
)
    ALTER TABLE Table_1 Drop Constraint DF_Table_1_col1
GO
```

I update the above command as follows since as I understand there is a misunderstanding

I assume now the schema for the table Leraar is Data
So please instead of dbo use Data as schema name

```
IF exists (
    SELECT * 
    FROM sys.default_constraints 
    WHERE 
        parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'Data.Leraar') and
        name  = 'Data.Leraar.IsGeheim.DefaultValue'
)
    ALTER TABLE Data.Leraar Drop Constraint [Data.Leraar.IsGeheim.DefaultValue]
GO
```

Comment: Is this table reached via remote server over Linked Server ?

Comment: I modified the code, I think there is dbo vs data schema name confusion

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('Con_First') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
   ALTER TABLE Customer DROP CONSTRAINT Con_First;
END
```

Here `Con_First` is the name of constraint you want to delete.

Comment: But I want to have a check in it if the constraint already exists

Comment: IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Leraar'))
 BEGIN 
ALTER TABLE [Data.Leraar] DROP CONSTRAINT [Data.Leraar.IsGeheim.DefaultValue] 
END 

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Leraar'))
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [Data].[Leraar] ADD  CONSTRAINT [Data.Leraar.IsGeheim.DefaultValue]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [IsGeheim]
END but this doesnt work

Comment: oke, but can you post the whole correct solution then. Thank you

Comment: Solved! Thank you all